# How to check whether two structure types are equal in c?

Tags: c

I have a bit-field structure "struct errors" of size 1 byte and I am using its data using a mask "ERR_MASK" as shown in below code.
My requirement is that if the type of the structure is changed, the mask need to be adapted accordingly.

Since I am importing this structure type from another component or module (file1.h in below code), 
I want to define a copy of this structure type "struct copy_errors" in my source file (file2.c in below code) and check if it has got changed with original type in file1.h, 
If there is a mismatch, I want to throw an compilation error from file2.c. Can anyone tell me how do I achieve this? Or is there any other way to do this? 
Note: I don't want to access "struct errors" with its elements.

```
    /*file1.h*/
    struct errors
    {
      unsigned char err0  :1;
      unsigned char err1  :1;
      unsigned char err2  :1;
      unsigned char err3  :1;
      unsigned char err4  :1;
      unsigned char err5  :1;
      unsigned char reserved1   :1;
      unsigned char reserved2   :1;

    };

    /*file2.c*/
    #include "file1.h"
    #define ERR_MASK 0xFCU

    struct copy_errors
    {
      unsigned char err0  :1;
      unsigned char err1  :1;
      unsigned char err2  :1;
      unsigned char err3  :1;
      unsigned char err4  :1;
      unsigned char err5  :1;
      unsigned char reserved1   :1;
      unsigned char reserved2   :1;

    };

    bool function(struct err*)
    {
      bool ret=0;
      unsigned char * err_ptr;

      err_ptr = (unsigned char *) err;

      if (((*err_ptr) & ERR_MASK) != 0U)
      {
        ret = 1;
      }

      return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a copy of a structure? Why can't you use the actual structure itself? Having a copy of a structure will just lead to maintenance nightmares if they ever get out of sync.

Comment: And besides, two different structures are two different structures. For the C compiler they really are two different structures, there's no relationship between them at all. Which of course means there's no way to get build errors if they don't match.

Comment: You could use some kind of `diff` tool, but I don't think there's any way to do it in the language itself.

Comment: This `struct* err` is not valid C, BTW.

Comment: ` of size 1 byte` - how do you know that? Are you sure?

Comment: `if (((*err_ptr) & ERR_MASK) != 0U)` Not portable. You are assuming about the bit layout which actually is implementation dependent. BTW to check such thing one way is to rely on manual and reliable (Does it exist) versioning.

Comment: Two different structs that are atually exactly the same? Why?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using the actual structure from file1.h but if its type is modified by file1 owner (which is not me), I want it to be notified to me in the form of compilation error. That is the reason why I want to keep a copy of it in my file (file2.c or file2.h) and do a pre-compile check.

Comment: Why don't you just use the one definition from the other file?  It would be far more sensible than what you're trying.  Do you really distrust your colleagues that much?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think you didn't understand my question. I am using the same definition from the other file. if the type is changed, it may be possible that the owner my forget to inform others and in this scenario, the check whatever i am doing using mask would lead to wrong results. To avoid this I want to put a check. it is not about trust, it is about miscommunication and possible error.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't support anything equivalent. If you have a tool chain that supports custom build events, you could introduce a pre-build step calling e. g. a python script (or any other language you prefer). This script then would:

- load the header file
- iterate over all lines until it finds the structure in question
- check for all known members in desired order (i. e. no members replaced)
- finally check, if end of structure is reached (i. e. no new members added)

If your tool chain stops, if the pre-build task fails, you are out already (just return 0 on success and anything else on failure), otherwise you could create a simple C-File, empty on success and containing an `#error` directive on failure.

Within your C code, you could additionally assure that the size of your struct matches:

```
#define CONCATENATE(X, Y) CONCATENATE_(X, Y)
#define CONCATENATE_(X, Y) X##Y

#define STATIC_ASSERT(CONDITION) \
    typedef int(CONCATENATE(_static_assert_, __LINE__))[(CONDITION)? 1 : -1]

STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(struct errors) == sizeof(unsigned char));
```

The macro is defined to be re-usable, as is, though, might produce additional warnings if used within function body (because of unused local type).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I forgot to clarify that the size of "struct errors" and "struct copy_errors" is always 1-byte. I want to identify if its elements have got interchanged or replaced with new elements.

Comment: @GirishOnte Well, forget about `copy_errors`, it doesn't serve you anything at all. All the checks you want/need can be done on `struct errors` directly – but apart from the size check, none of them directly from within C. It's not supported. Fullstop. So you need a separate tool for, like forementioned python script (or any other scripting language or even a *separate* executable written in C).

Comment: @GirishOnte  Size will always be 1 byte? Are you sure? What about this: `struct errors { unsigned char err0:1; /* ... */ unsigned char err5:1; unsigned char err6:1; unsigned char err7:1; unsigned char err8:1; /* and a bunch of reserved bits */ };`...

Comment: Yes. I got to know that this is not possible from C language. I will check for the tool solution as you suggested. thanks. To clarify you regarding size, the number of elements of the structure are always fixed in my application. They are not going to vary. but the position of existing elements can be altered inside the structure. hope it is clear.